# Specifying Which User Can Access Certain Data With MySQL and Python

Tags: python, mysql

I am creating a python program that encrypts a file, stores the key to MySQL, and you can access this key later for decryption. How would I make its so only certain users can access any number of keys. I want to add a whitelisting feature where you can add users who can use your keys. I have a login and register system already set up.

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import os, mysql.connector, hashlib

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="Removed",
    password="Removed",
    database="Removed"
)

cursor = mydb.cursor()

def encode(inFile, tag):
    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    sql = "INSERT INTO keydb (EncryptionKey, Tags) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    inp = (key, tag)
    cursor.execute(sql, inp)
    mydb.commit()
    f = Fernet(key)
    f.encrypt(inFile)

 
def login(Username, password):
    hashpass = hashlib.sha1(password.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE Username=%s AND Password=%s"
    cursor.execute(sql, (Username, hashpass))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    if result:
        savedUser = result[0]
        savedPass = result[1]
        if savedUser == Username and savedPass == hashpass:
            print("Login Success")
            return True
        else:
            print("Login Failed")
    


def register(Username, Password):
    hashpass = hashlib.sha1(Password.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    sql = "INSERT INTO login (Username, Password) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    cursor.execute(sql, (Username, hashpass))
    mydb.commit()
    
OpType = input("Login or Register: ")
if OpType == 'Login':
    User = input("What is your username? ")
    Pass = input("What is your password? ")
    loginSuccess = login(User, Pass)
elif OpType == 'Register':
    User = input("What is your username? ")
    Pass = input("What is your password? ")
    register(User, Pass)

if loginSuccess == True:
    NewOpType = input("What Operation do you want to do (Encrypt or Decrypt?) ")
    if NewOpType == 'Encrypt':
        file, tag = input("What file do you want to encrypt? "), input("What do you want to tag it with? ")
        for files in os.listdir():
            if file == files:
                encode(file, tag)
```

Comment: Use a table `key_access` that contains foreign keys into `keydb` and `login`. This links keys to the users that have access to them. When someone tries to use a key, check that they have an entry there.